# Decltype with template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, decltype

Below *test1.cpp* compiles, but *test2.cpp* does not.  The only difference between the two is that I define `Handle::add_it` within the class declaration in *test1.cpp*, but outside in *test2.cpp*.

**test1.cpp**:
*g++ test1.cpp -o test1 -std=c++11*

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename B>
class Handle
{
public:
        decltype(B.operator(int)) add_it(int x)
        {
                return b(x);
        }

        B b;
};

struct Add1
{
        int operator()(int x)
        {
                return x + 1;
        }
};

int main()
{
        Handle<Add1> h;
        std::cout << h.add_it(5) << std::endl;
}
```

**test2.cpp**:
*g++ test2.cpp -o test2 -std=c++11*

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename B>
class Handle
{
public:
        decltype(B.operator(int)) add_it(int x);

        B b;
};

template<typename B>
decltype(B.operator(int)) Handle<B>::add_it(int x)
{
        return b(x);
}

struct Add1
{
        int operator()(int x)
        {
                return x + 1;
        }
};

int main()
{
        Handle<Add1> h;
        std::cout << h.add_it(5) << std::endl;
}
```

**Errors**

```
test2.cpp:13:11: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
 decltype(B.operator(int))
           ^
test2.cpp:13:20: error: expected type-specifier before ‘(’ token
 decltype(B.operator(int))
                    ^
test2.cpp:13:21: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
 decltype(B.operator(int))
```

Comment: what is `B.operator(int)` supposed to be? #1 is rejected by clang and I don't see how it is valid syntax or why g++ accepts it

Comment: In this case it was suppose to be `int`, but in my actual application I want it to be general (both the argument and return value of `B`'s `operator()`).  I don't know why g++ accepts it, curious myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can amend this by using `std::declval`:

```
template<typename B>
class Handle
{
public:
  decltype(std::declval<B>()(int())) add_it(int x) {
    return b(x);
  }

  B b;
};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dfe9f11225d508c7)

Or outside the definition of the class:

```
template<typename B>
class Handle {
public:
  decltype(std::declval<B>()(int())) add_it(int x);
  B b;
};

template<typename B>
decltype(std::declval<B>()(int())) Handle<B>::add_it(int x) {
  return b(x);
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea7fa12c6833ef58)

Comment: You probably want to define `Handle<B>::add_it` [outside the class declaration](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebba4941d759e1e5), since that's failing for the OP.